UK visitor Visa refusal on not meeting requirements of paragraph(s) V4.2 of Appendix V
I had applied for for 14 days to attend a relative wedding together with a minor son. They say I didn't demonstrate the circumstances or current whereabouts of any immediate family member, who may be remaining in my home country upon departure.
My son lives in a different country although he visits on school holidays.
I am from Africa
I want to reapply - What should I do to make sure this time it goes through.
Due to the time limit, I want to apply alone as the logistics involved with my son are too much as he has to travel for 10 hours for Biometrics

Do you have any immediate family members who will be remaining in your home country? It doesn't sound like it from the question. This question discusses how to prove you have such a family member, e.g. marriage certificate or proof you are caring for an elderly/disabled relative. Else you may have to prove other ties to your home country; there are probably questions about that too.
